# logits and labels must be broadcastable

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I've started tensorflow and trying to implement simple neural network with identify the digit practice problem from analyticsvidhya.com with followed this post: 
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/10/an-introduction-to-implementing-neural-networks-using-tensorflow/

here is my full code:
https://github.com/NilSagor/AV_ml_practice/blob/master/digit_reco/digit_practise_01.ipynb

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(
    logits =output_layer, labels =y))
```

**error: logits and labels must be broadcastable**

image reshape

```
temp = []
for img_name in train.filename:
    image_path = os.path.join(data_dir, 'train', 'Images', 'train', img_name)
    img = Image.open(filepath)
    img= np.array(img).astype('float32')
    temp.append(img)

train_x = np.stack(temp)

temp = []
for img_name in test.filename:
    image_path = os.path.join(data_dir, 'train', 'Images', 'test', img_name)   
    img = Image.open(filepath)    
    img= np.array(img).astype('float32')
    temp.append(img)

test_x = np.stack(temp)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        avg_cost = 0
        total_batch = int(train_data.shape[0]//batch_size)
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = batch_creator(batch_size, train_x.shape[0], 'train')

            _,c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
            avg_cost += c/total_batch
        print("Epoch: ", (epoch+1), "cost: ", "{:.5f}".format(avg_cost))
    print("Training complete")
```

and batch_creator funciton

```
def batch_creator(batch_size, dataset_length, dataset_name):
    """ Create batch with random samples and return appropiate format"""
    batch_mask = rng.choice(dataset_length, batch_size)
    batch_x = eval(dataset_name + "_x")[[batch_mask]].reshape(-1, input_num_units)
    batch_x = preproc(batch_x)
    if dataset_name == "train":
        batch_y = eval(dataset_name).ix[batch_mask, 'label'].values
        batch_y = dense_to_one_hot(batch_y)

    return batch_x, batch_y

weights = {
    'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_num_units, hidden_num_units], seed = seed)),
    'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_num_units, output_num_units], seed = seed))
}

biases = {
    'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_num_units], seed = seed)),
    'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([output_num_units], seed = seed))
```

}

```
hidden_layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['hidden']), biases['hidden'])
hidden_layer = tf.nn.relu(hidden_layer)
output_layer = tf.matmul(hidden_layer, weights['output']) + biases['output']



cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits =output_layer, labels =y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

how to get rid of the error and how to create batch for efficiently?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When `if dataset_name == "train_data":` is not true `batch_y` is not defined, hence the error.

Comment: @jdehesa I've updated if dataset_name == "train" but now error is showing **InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[512,10] labels_size=[128,10]
  [[{{node softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_6}}]]**

Comment: `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`  also gives **InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [512,10] vs. [128,10]** error

Comment: can you add your data manipulation part?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
    from matplotlib.pyplot import imread
    img = imread(image_path)
```

with

```
    from scipy.misc import imread
    img = imread(image_path, flatten=True)
```

This is what has been done in the above post and it's important because along with reading image, it's also flattening the color layers into a single gray-scale layer. In your case, `(28, 28, 4)` to `(28, 28)`.

Comment: `from scipy.misc import imread` is deprecated, updated with preprocess